# Pourquoi « absorption » et pas « absorbsion »?

Tags: orthographe, vocabulaire

Cette question me taraude<sup>1</sup> depuis que j'ai perdu un point à l'école à cause d'elle. Puisqu'*absorption* est l'[action d'absorber](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/absorption), pourquoi ne l'écrit-on pas *absorbsion* ?

Tant qu'à faire, pourquoi pas non plus *aptorption* ? Y a-t-il une différence phonétique entre *bs* et *pt* ?

---

<sup>1. J'ajouterais bien « tel le ver un vieux meuble », mais ce serait du plagiat.</sup>

Comment: bsain, la différence phonétique elle est quand même évidente ;-)

Comment: (Pardon, c'est vrai que quand le *t* est prononcé `/s/` ça s'entend beaucoup moins.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Le verbe *absorber* dérive du verbe latin *[absorbere](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/absorbeo#la)*, et plus particulièrement du radical de l'infinitif. Le nom *absorption* dérive du nom latin *[absorptio](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/absorptio#la)*. Il faut donc remonter au latin pour la transformation du `b` en `p`. Cette évolution s'explique certainement par la difficulté de la succession `[bt]` qui se transforme naturellement en `[pt]`.

Le suffixe *[-tion](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-tion)* est dérivé du suffixe latin *-tio*, et est resté productif en français. Ce suffixe nominatif peut aussi, plus rarement, prendre la forme *-sion* ; l'article du *Trésor de la langue française* explore la répartition. Là encore, la distinction remonte au latin : *tension* de *[tensio](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tensio#la)*, *dissension* de *[dissensio](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dissensio)*, *appréhension* de *[apprehensio](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apprehensio)*, mais *question* de *[quaestio](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quaestio#la)*, *attention* de *[attentio](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/attention)*, ... Souvent, le nom est formé en latin sur le même radical que le [supin](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supin) du verbe, et un verbe existe, formé sur le radical du présent du verbe latin (*tendre*, *appréhender*, *quérir*, *attendre*, ...). Comme souvent en français, on a gardé l'orthographe éymologique en `-tion` même après que la prononciation eut évolué.

Pour ce qui est du préfixe, l'évolution de la prononciation est différente : le `[b]` s'est transformé en présence d'un `[s]` et non d'un `[t]`. Faire suivre un [`[b]`](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/API_b) par un `[s]` tend à transformer la consonne [bilabiale](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_bilabiale) en une [labio-dentale](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_labio-dentale), pour faire faire par la mâchoire supérieure ce que les lèvres ont du mal à faire seule (dans l'autre direction, le `[s]` pourrait se transformer en `[z]`). Comme le français n'a pas de phonème [`[b̪]`](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/API_b%CC%AA), on le rend par la consonne [sourde](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_sourde) [`[p]`](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/API_p), même si en pratique elle est plutôt prononcée à mi-chemin entre `[b]` et `[p]`.

Comment: Donc, si je suis bien, _absorption_ remplace _absorbtion_ et pas _absorbsion_ ?

Comment: @Joubarc L'orthographe est déjà `-ptio` en latin, à ma connaissance avec la prononciation `/pt/` au moins en latin classique. Je ne sais pas de quand date la prononciation en `/s/` pour la finale *-tion*.

Comment: Formation savante par opposition à formation populaire je présume !